# Sympy plotting x-axis in wrong location?

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

I am plotting a function using Sympy and the X axis is way above where it should be. The numbering of the y axis is correct but for some reason the x axis is [zeroed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGGn3.png) at around 28.75. I have tried setting axis_center="auto" instead of "center" which changed nothing.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import *
import spb
import sympy as sympy




question = "100*(x)**2-30*x+30"

x,y = symbols("x y")
# [[-2.0, 2.3], [26.75, 31.0]]

plot = spb.plot(eval(question), (x, -2.0, 2.3), {"color": f"blue", "markersize": "1"}, legend=False, aspect="equal", ylim=(
                26.75, 31), xlim=(-2.0, 2.3), show=True, adaptive=False, n=70000, is_point=True,axis_center="auto")
```

Comment: You set `ylim=(26.75, 31)`, so where do you expect the x-axis to be? If you want it a y=0, then change ylim. [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPhKz.png) or this [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3sXt.png). This does not seem like there is an issue. As such, I'm voting to close this as *not reproducible*.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney In your examples despite changing the yLim the x-axis is still in the wrong location (y=15 in the first example),  or turned off. I want to be able to show a specific portion of the plot with the x and y axis still showing and centered at origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here you can read the documentation](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/backends/matplotlib.html) associated to `MatplotlibBackend`, which is used by default by `spb`. In particular:

```
axis_center(float, float) or str or None, optional
    Set the location of the intersection between the horizontal and vertical axis in a 2D plot. It can be:

        * None: traditional layout, with the horizontal axis fixed on the bottom and the vertical axis fixed on the left. This is the default value.
        * a tuple (x, y) specifying the exact intersection point.
        * 'center': center of the current plot area.
        * 'auto': the intersection point is automatically computed.
```

Let's run a simple snippet of code to visualize the differences:

```py
from sympy import *
import spb
question = "100*(x)**2-30*x+30"

x,y = symbols("x y")

create = lambda axis_center: spb.plot(eval(question), (x, -2.0, 2.3),
     legend=False, aspect="equal",
     ylim=(26.75, 31), xlim=(-2.0, 2.3), adaptive=False,
     is_point=False,axis_center=axis_center, show=False,
    title=f"axis_center={axis_center}")
p1 = create(None)
p2 = create("center")
p3 = create("auto")
p4 = create((0, 28))
spb.plotgrid(p1, p2, p3, p4, nc=2)
```

[image]

Clearly, you can see the differences between `"auto"` and `"center"`. I guess you'd have to play with the tuple in order to set the position of the intersection at your desired location.